# MySQL set column as CONCAT of other columns in the same table on INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table for storing details of uploaded files, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE files (
    file_id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
    file_name text,
    file_path text,
    file_extension varchar(15),
    file_link text);
```

The actual name of the file on the disk is set to the `file_id` generated by the table when I insert the record - so although I can record all sorts of details, the database doesn't actually know what the file is called at this point.

Sure it's easy to just run another `UPDATE` statement shortly after to set the `file_link` column, but I wondered if there was a way to do something a bit more elegant here?

What I would like to do is have the value of `file_link` be automatically set on `INSERT` to this: `CONCAT(file_path, file_id, file_extension)` without needing to run another `UPDATE` statement immediately after.

Does anyone know how I can do this - and if it's a bad idea can you explain why?

P.S I'm using PHP to run these statements, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @etherbunny mostly to cut down on the complexity of the SELECT statements I'm going to be using in more than one place - although eventually I'm most likely going to remove the file_path and file_extension columns if I can get the file_link set on INSERT. But yes you're right, it is redundant

Comment: I would be inclined to do the opposite: remove the file_link and keep the file_path. That way if you have to move the files on the server its trivial to update the path. If you have the path as part of the file_link then changing it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @ethrbunny so you'd favour calculating the file location in the SELECT each time (or using a view), and forgetting about storing the path? this occurred to me too, I can see the wisdom in it. posibility of moving the files might come up to good to be flexible. In case you hadn't guessed, this is related to my last question also - I've got date-named directories now :)

Comment: Typically you don't want to store derived data.

Comment: @ethrbunny just my straight-forward way of thinking I suppose lol. If you put that in an answer I'll probably accept, doesn't look like anyone else has a better idea at this point anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER makelink BEFORE INSERT ON files
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      SET NEW.file_link = CONCAT(NEW.file_path, NEW.file_id, NEW.file_extension);
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

...although I have to say, I personally would go with creating this with the `SELECT` statement instead of having the database do things like this on insert - sure it's slightly more efficient to store static data, but it makes the database schema less transparent.

Comment: Just for future reference, I'm doing this in the select as suggested by you and @ethrbunny - but +1 for trigger :)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't want to store derived data. Do some reading on db normalization when you have some spare cycles.